# How to create a data extension from a Mobile List?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, mobileconnect, contact-deletion

We have created a filtered list in Contact Builder:
Contact Key not null AND
Email Address null AND
Mobile Number null AND
Device ID null AND
CUSTOMER_ID null
This lit identifies the subscribers that can be deleted.

We want to create a data extension from this list, and use this new data extension to delete the subscribers.
Any tips on how to create this DE from the list?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in this [KA article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000313920&type=1)

> 2. Use a SQL Query Activity to query from this list into a new Data Extension (DE).
>    i. Within the Query, select the "Overwrite" Data Action. If either of the other options is selected you will get a Primary Key error.
> 3. Create a new DE with one field titled SubscriberKey, make this field a Primary Key. Make the DE sendable.
> 4. In Automation Studio, create an SQL query that resembles the below.

```
select subscriberkey 
from [name of MobileConnect/MobilePush filtered list name]
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked"